# GLib-ERROR **: Cannot create pipe main loop wake-up: Too many open files

Tags: python

I am running two functions in parallel using python's multiprocessing library. The code reads data from a file, inserts the data into the database, and records any errors to an error file. This program is being run indefinitely. After the first cycle I have been getting an error: `GLib-ERROR **: Cannot create pipe main loop wake-up: Too many open files`. I am not sure where this is coming from since I make sure to open and  close the files after use. I have some sample code below

```
     class DataProcessing:
          def __init___(configlog,sleeptime,logfile):
              self.configlog = configlog
              self.sleeptime = sleeptime
              self.logfile = logfile
              self.manageClient()
              self.setupDB()

          def manageClient(self):
              s=subprocess.Popen([run streaming software])
              time.sleep(self.sleeptime)
              s.kill()
              del s
              self.stream = []
              with open(self.logfile) as f:
                   for line in f.readLines():
                        if "Data" in line:
                             self.stream.append(line)
          def setupDB(self):
              """"Set up connection to database using MySQLdb library"""

          def pushData(self):
              errorfile = open("errorlog.log","a")
               for line in self.stream:
                   """Check of for existing stream in DB. Update record in DB"""
                   try:
                       cur.execute(sql_query) 
                       db.commit()
                   except MySQLdb, e:
                        errorfile.write(e + "\n")
                        db.rollback()
                errorfile.close()
                cur.close()
                db.close()

     def firstProcess():
         while True:
             initialProcess = DataProcessing("configlog",300,"logfile.log")
             initialProcess.pushData()
     def secondProcess():
          while True:
              finalProcess = DataProcessing("otherlog",86000,"otherlog.log")
              finalProcess.pushData()

     p1 = Process(target = firstProcess)
     p1.start()
     p2 = Process(target = secondProcess)
     p2.start()
```

Comment: It's not Python that's printing the message, it's something linked with GLib. You need to show a complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @RossRidge I don't think I can get more specific than that. Although I realized that the streaming software drastically increased the number of open file descriptors above the hard limit which seems to be why I am getting that error.